# Toggle a character using a pointer

Tags: c

To toggle a character with a return value, I can do something like the following:

```
char toggle_char(char my_char) {
    return my_char ^ 0x20;
}

int main(void) {

    char my_char = 'a';
    my_char = toggle_char(my_char);
    printf("My Char: %c\n", my_char);
    my_char = toggle_char(my_char);
    printf("My Char: %c\n", my_char);

    return 0;
}
```

How would I do the same using an in-place pointer? For example, I could do this:

```
int main(void) {
    char my_char = 'a';
    printf("My Char: %c\n", my_char);
    toggle_char(my_char);
    printf("My Char: %c\n", my_char);
}
```

Comment: `^ 0x20` curiously looks like code is toggling the _case_.  Could use `^ ('A' ^ 'a')` instead.  Works for [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) letters too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making changes in-place means that you are working on the same address location, and not using some other temporary addressed variable.

So here you need to pass the address of your variable to the function and function signature must be taking a pointer to the variable as the parameter.

Your function will be something like

```
void toggle_char(char *my_char) {
    *my_char ^= 0x20;
}
```

And you need to call it as

`toggle_char(&my_char);`

Answer (score 0):

With something like

```
void toggle_char(char *my_char) {
    *my_char ^= 0x20;
}
```

and passing the function the address of the variable in question.